# Trying to draw a line with Kivy and threading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, kivy

I am making a Kivy application right now, and in one part of it, I am getting data as an array of floating point numbers and I want to draw a line in Kivy using the data.
The problem is, I want it to constantly run, so I used threading, but Kivy would not draw the line. here is a stripped down version of the code that illustrates the problem:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Line
from threading import Thread


class MyWidget(Widget):
   def Draw(self):
       with self.canvas:
           Line(points=[100, 200, 300, 400])
class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()




Thread(target=MyWidget().Draw).start()
MainApp().run()
```

I want this code to draw a line with points 100, 200, 300, 400.

but instead, the app opens and does nothing, help will be appreciated!

Comment: Drawing operations must be performed from the main thread. Try running `Clock.schedule_once(your_drawing_function, 0)` for the function that does the drawing, instead of running it directly from the thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified your example a bit.
Try start the thread in the init method instead. Because when you do `MyWidget().Draw`, you do that with a new `MyWidget` object, and not the one you returned in your build method. So that line will never be drawn. But the line in another widget which is not on the screen.
Try like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Line, InstructionGroup
from threading import Thread
from random import randint
import time



class MyWidget(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.ig = InstructionGroup()
        self.line = Line(points=[100, 200, 300, 400])
        self.ig.add(self.line)
        self.canvas.add(self.ig)

        Thread(target=self.draw).start()


    def draw(self):
        while True:
            self.line.points = [randint(0,400) for i in range(4)]
            time.sleep(0.5)



class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()



MainApp().run()
```

Comment: @TalK you are wellcome.